# Triggering click events from within a FF sandbox

Tags: firefox-addon, click, event-delegation, dom, event-dispatching

I am trying to trigger a click event on an element on a page from within a Firefox sandbox. I have tried using jQuery's .click() as well as doing:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, false );
toClick[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Has anyone been able to trigger a click event on a page in the browser through a sandbox? I can get the DOM element fine, but triggering the event is a different story.

Comment: What do you mean by a "Firefox sandbox"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the event on the right document:

```
var evt = pageDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, false );
toClick[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
```

The `true` means the event "bubbles" and the `false` means the event cannot be cancelled. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent

Comment: I edited your answer to include a description of what the boolean params to initEvent mean, plus a link. Hope you don't mind!